# untar extracts files as different user

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm running on Ubuntu server as root user (according to whoami).

I'm trying to untar a package. Unfortunately the untarred folder and all files are somehow owned by another user (zabbix).

I did install zabbix recently but I am logged in as root so I expect the untarred files to be owened by root. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tar` encodes the numeric id of the owner and primary group of every file. When you untar a tarball all the owners will be set back to their original numeric id's, for example uid 500. What you have is the `zabbix` user in your system created as uid 500. Hence, when you restore the archive, the files appear to be owned by zabbix.

To confirm, try

`id zabbix` and `ls -aln $DIRECTORY`

My guess is they will be the same.

Answer (score 6):

Add the `--no-same-owner` parameter to your command (assuming a gnu tar). When running as root, tar automatically preservers file ownership and permissions.

As an aside: Are you sure you really need to be doing whatever you're doing as root?

Comment: do you mean that the tar i'm untarring was tarred by owner zabbix? it is the latest distribution of memcached so it does not make sense to me.

Comment: @Niro No, the tar wasn't tarred by owner zabbix. It was probably tarred by a user with with the same user id as the user zabbix has on your system. Since uids aren't universally unique, this can easily happen.